# How to create custom List item dynamically with Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

You can copy/paste the following code in Notepad or whatever :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum- scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   require(["dojox/mobile/parser",
            "dijit/registry",
            "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
            "dojox/mobile",
            "dojo/domReady!"],function(parser,registry){
             parser.parse();
             var list = registry.byId("list");
             for(var i = 0;i < 18;i++){
                var childWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({id:"item"+i,  
                                                          label:"ITEM"+i});

                list.addChild(childWidget);

             }
             document.getElementById("item0").style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
             document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundColor = "green"; 

           });
    </script>




  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="settings" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" data-dojo-props="selected: true">

  <!-- a sample heading -->
  <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">Settings</h1>

  <!-- a rounded rectangle list container -->
  <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList" id="list">
  </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="article" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">

    <!-- a sample heading -->
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props='back: "settings",moveTo: "settings"'>Article</h1>

    This is the article view
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

However the part of the code I'm struggling with is :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   require(["dojox/mobile/parser",
            "dijit/registry",
            "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
            "dojox/mobile",
            "dojo/domReady!"],function(parser,registry){
             parser.parse();
             var list = registry.byId("list");
             for(var i = 0;i < 18;i++){
                var childWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({id:"item"+i,  
                                                          label:"ITEM"+i});

                list.addChild(childWidget);

             }
             document.getElementById("item0").style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
             document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundColor = "green"; 

           });
    </script>
```

As you can see ListItems are created dynamically like this :

```
var childWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({id:"item"+i,label:"ITEM"+i});
```

What I'd like to do is to put a background color at the creation of the ItemList instead of putting it after as you can see the 2 lines with "red" and "green".

So I'm looking for something like this :

```
var childWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({id:"item"+i,label:"ITEM"+i,style=????});
```

But there isn't such a **style** property.

Properties [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/ListItem.html) btw.

Is it possible to do it ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend you to add ListItem to your AMD dependency list and use it just as any other AMD module:

```
require(["dojox/mobile/ListItem"], function(ListItem) {
   new ListItem(...);
});
```

and not through the old dojox.mobile notation.

For your styling issue, the solution your are hinting at can actually be applied, ListItem are inheriting for dijit/_WidgetBase and as such will support the style property. Something like the following should work:

```
new ListItem({id: "theid", label: "thelabel", style: "background-color: red"});
```